# Как собрать проект Java Spring Boot с помощью Gradle и JDK находящейся в директории не являющейся директорией по умолчанию?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-ee, gradle

Есть сервер Ubuntu c JDK 8, есть проект  Java Spring Boot разработанный под JDK 11.
На сервере JDK 8 по умолчанию я поменять не могу, но могу залить на сервер архив с JDK 11.
Как можно сбилдить проект с использованием JDK 11 Gradle из консоли сервера?

Можно как-то для этого использовать стандартную команду билда Gradle "./gradlew clean build -b name/build.gradle -x test"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете указать путь к JDK при сборке с помощью параметра `org.gradle.java.home`

```
gradle -Dorg.gradle.java.home={Путь к скачанной JDK}
```

В целом сценарий будет выглядеть примерно так:

Скачиваете Gradle

```
wget https://downloads.gradle-dn.com/distributions/gradle-7.0-all.zip
```

Распаковываете Gradle в нужную папку на сервере

```
unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-7.0-all.zip
```

Скачиваете JDK 11

```
wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/9/GPL/openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

Распаковываете JDK 11 в нужную папку на сервере

```
tar --directory=/opt/java -xf openjdk-11.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

Если не установлен tar

```
sudo apt-get install tar
```

Переходите в папку с проектом

```
cd /home/rebrov/projects/stackoverflow_answer/
```

Далее можете запустить команду Gradle указав путь до бинарника Gradle и указав в параметрах путь к нужной JDK

```
/opt/gradle/gradle-7.0/bin/gradle -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/opt/java/jdk-11.0.2/ build
```

#### Замечания:

- Gradle поддерживает 11-ую Java, начиная с пятой версии